# Can't paste into text input in FF

Tags: firefox, input, copy-paste

This has me stumped. I have built A custom form to put new albums in my db. When I copy from Excel I don't have a problem. I can paste whatever cell contents I have copied into my input. If I try copy from phpmyadmin where it is an ID that looks up to another table that is a link it doesn't paste into the input. Also copying from open office doesn't work but if you copy, then paste it into another cell in openoffice then go to my page the paste works. Also the copy works fine in IE. This is very confusing. Copy/paste works on every other site, so I'm guessing this might be a coding problem?

This is my input

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $catno ?>" name="catno" 
id="catno"  onchange="editCatNo();"  class="normalInput" />
```

I have an ajax function attached to each input. I have removed it from the input but that didn't help.

Here's my css

```
.normalInput {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:solid 1px #009137;
    font-size:16px;
    width:200px;
}
```

And Here's my javascrpit

```
function editCatNo() {
  var value = $("#catno").val();
  var div = "#CAT_NO";
  var id = $("#id").val();
  var table = 'catelogue';
  var column = 'CAT_NO';
  $.ajax({
    url: "Ajax/Update/updateAll.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id:id, value:value, table:table, column:column},
    beforeSend: function() {
     $(div).empty().append("<img src='Images/preLoader.gif'/>");
      },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            $(div).empty();
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            $(div).empty();
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            $(div).empty();
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            $(div).empty();
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
            $(div).empty();
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            $(div).empty();
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            $(div).empty();
        }
    },
    success: function(results) { 
      $(div).empty().append(results);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most things on windows, a reboot fixed the problem.